# Where is the symlink created for a generated Yocto sdcard image

Tags: yocto, meta-raspberrypi

I modified an existing Yocto class (sdcard_image-rpi.bbclass) which generates an SD card image. The new class has a different name as well. Everything works as expected with one exception. When bitbake is finished, symlinks are created, which point to the last built file. For the .sdcard file this symlink is not created.

It is only not clear to me where (or in which stage) this symlink should be created.

Any suggestions what might causing this ?

class file content added below. (Removed the partitioning and copy opererations for clarity). This file is derived from meta-raspberrypi
and on some locations the name "rpi-sdimg" is replaced by "dual-sdimg".

The original file does not contain a command to create a symlink to the generated sdcard image, which implies it should be done outside this class. Most likely the changed name influenced this.

```
    inherit image_types



# This image depends on the rootfs image
IMAGE_TYPEDEP_dual-sdimg = "${SDIMG_ROOTFS_TYPE}"       # Name changed

# Set kernel and boot loader
IMAGE_BOOTLOADER ?= "bootfiles"

# Kernel image name
SDIMG_KERNELIMAGE_raspberrypi  ?= "kernel.img"
SDIMG_KERNELIMAGE_raspberrypi2 ?= "kernel7.img"
SDIMG_KERNELIMAGE_raspberrypi3-64 ?= "kernel8.img"

# Boot partition volume id
BOOTDD_VOLUME_ID ?= "${MACHINE}"


# Use an uncompressed ext3 by default as rootfs
SDIMG_ROOTFS_TYPE ?= "ext3"
SDIMG_ROOTFS = "${IMGDEPLOYDIR}/${IMAGE_LINK_NAME}.${SDIMG_ROOTFS_TYPE}"

# For the names of kernel artifacts
inherit kernel-artifact-names

RPI_SDIMG_EXTRA_DEPENDS ?= ""

do_image_dual_sdimg[depends] = " \                  # Name changed
    parted-native:do_populate_sysroot \
    mtools-native:do_populate_sysroot \
    dosfstools-native:do_populate_sysroot \
    virtual/kernel:do_deploy \
    ${IMAGE_BOOTLOADER}:do_deploy \
    rpi-config:do_deploy \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('MACHINE_FEATURES', 'armstub', 'armstubs:do_deploy', '' ,d)} \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('RPI_USE_U_BOOT', '1', 'u-boot:do_deploy', '',d)} \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('RPI_USE_U_BOOT', '1', 'u-boot-default-script:do_deploy', '',d)} \
    ${RPI_SDIMG_EXTRA_DEPENDS} \
"

do_image_rpi_sdimg[recrdeps] = "do_build"

# SD card image name
SDIMG = "${IMGDEPLOYDIR}/${IMAGE_NAME}${IMAGE_NAME_SUFFIX}.rpi-sdimg"

# Additional files and/or directories to be copied into the vfat partition from the IMAGE_ROOTFS.
FATPAYLOAD ?= ""

# SD card vfat partition image name
SDIMG_VFAT_DEPLOY ?= "${RPI_USE_U_BOOT}"
SDIMG_VFAT = "${IMAGE_NAME}.vfat"
SDIMG_LINK_VFAT = "${IMGDEPLOYDIR}/${IMAGE_LINK_NAME}.vfat"



IMAGE_CMD_dual-sdimg () {


    echo "Creating SD card image of ${SDIMG_SIZE} KiB with a boot partition of ${PT_BOOT_SIZE_ALIGNED} KiB and a rootfs of ${PT_ROOTFS_SIZE_ALIGNED} KiB"

    # Check if we are building with device tree support
    DTS="${KERNEL_DEVICETREE}"

    # Initialize sdcard image file
    dd if=/dev/zero of=${SDIMG} bs=1024 count=0 seek=${SDIMG_SIZE}

    # Partitioning here

    # Create a vfat image with boot files

    # Bootloader copying here

    # Add files (eg. hypervisor binaries) from the deploy dir

    # Add stamp file

    # Deploy vfat partition

    # Write partitions to image file
}

ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += " rpi_generate_sysctl_config ; "

rpi_generate_sysctl_config() {
    # systemd sysctl config
    test -d ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/sysctl.d && \
        echo "vm.min_free_kbytes = 8192" > ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/sysctl.d/rpi-vm.conf

    # sysv sysctl config
    IMAGE_SYSCTL_CONF="${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/sysctl.conf"
    test -e ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/sysctl.conf && \
        sed -e "/vm.min_free_kbytes/d" -i ${IMAGE_SYSCTL_CONF}
    echo "" >> ${IMAGE_SYSCTL_CONF} && echo "vm.min_free_kbytes = 8192" >> ${IMAGE_SYSCTL_CONF}
}
```

Comment: You should show your changes, otherwise its hard to help

Comment: Added excerpt from bbclass.